# Where are the DNS resolvers?

Tags: dns-spoofing

I'm trying to understand the principle behind DNS poisoning attacks. It seems like the DNS Resolver is just a piece of software. Where is this software located, and how is it shared among all the computers on the network?

To actually poison a record, the attacker would need to have access to the same resolver as well right? Would this software have to be on my router for example? If you put the resolver on your local computer, would you be impervious to DNS poisoning?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is mainly not a security question. It essentially asks how DNS works in the first place.

Comment: You might start with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#DNS_resolvers) to get some understanding of what DNS resolvers are and how do they work in the context of DNS. And Wikipedia even provides you with information about DNS poisoning.

Comment: It seems like a rather basic question, but it does not seem off-topic.

Comment: @forest: I disagree. Asking of how DNS poisoning works would be on-topic. Asking about DNSSec would be on-topic too. But asking the basics of how DNS works  in the first place like the OP does (i.e. where are the DNS resolvers and what are they actually?) is in my opinion not (yet) about security.